# Desktop freezes with Cinnamon 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon

I've installed Cinnamon on Ubuntu 16.04. So far, everything but the Desktop is working. I can move the mouse around but clicking in the desktop icons doesn't do anything, I can only click the menu and the tray icons. Works fine after a reboot, but after some point it happens again.

PD: Ubuntu 16.04 is a requirement so I cannot upgrade it.

Comment: How about updating to a more recent Ubuntu?

Comment: Please try 18.04.2 LTS http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/ubuntu-releases/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso , just for troubleshooting purposes, and then click [edit] and report the result. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Upgrading Ubuntu is not an option. 16.04 is a requirement. Should have mentioned that.